# Impedence of 90° out of phase Capacitor and Inductor in parallel

Tags: capacitor, inductor, impedance

I'm curious as to what the equivalent impedance would be of these two elements. Mathematically it seems that they would have **infinite impedance** (meaning an open circuit), but this doesn't make any sense logically. If anyone could shed some light on this it would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Hint: what are the admittances of these two components?

Comment: @ThePhoton Oh wow, I guess that works as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it may seem counter-intuitive, a parallel combination an inductor and capacitor will behave like an open circuit where their impedances match; even more counter-intuitively, a series combination will appear like a dead short under such conditions!

Essentially what happens is that in the parallel case, any voltage which is applied will cause equal and opposite (relative to the applied voltage) currents to flow in the capacitor and inductor, so all current that flows through the inductor will also flow through the capacitor in a loop, without any current flowing through the source of the applied AC voltage.

In the series case, any current which flows through the inductor will also flow through the capacitor; this will cause the voltage drop of each device to be precisely cancelled out by the other, so the net voltage drop across the series string will be precisely zero.

Note that these precise cancellations only happen at the resonant frequency of the LC combination.  At other frequencies, the effects of one or the other component will dominate.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what supercat said in his nice answer, I'll add that the situation described is purely theoretical (but still useful in circuit analysis).

That situation assumes an ideal capacitor and an ideal inductor, which are only mathematical abstractions. Any real component suffers from some parasitic effect that will alter its ideal behavior. As a first level approximation consider this: a real capacitor has some leakage current, which can be modeled by a resistor in parallel to the ideal capacitor, whereas an inductor has some wire resistance, which can be modeled as a resistor in series with the ideal inductor.

If you add those parasitic elements to the circuit above and redo the math, you will see that at resonance the parallel LC circuit no longer has infinite impedance. Actually it becomes an RLC circuit!